# Why did a full TeXLive 2016 install on macOS Sierra not include Tk for `tlmgr --gui`?

Tags: texlive-2016, tlmgr, macos

I have a clean, full install of TeXLive 2016 on macOS Sierra on a new laptop.

I discovered that `tlmgr --gui` wasn't working, saying it needed `perl-tk`. Which, I'm ok with in theory, but going to the site that it suggests for more info (http://tug.org/texlive/distro.html#perltk) does me little good. It's exclusively directed toward solving this problem on Linux not macOS.

It's not straightfowardly `brew`-able, but I'm guessing I just need to track down `perl-tk` to make this possible. If anyone has tips for that I'm happy to receive them, but that's not the core of my question (just context for understanding where I'm coming from).

On previous versions of OSX I've not run into this problem with `tlmgr --gui`; just installing the full version from TeXLive was sufficient, which makes me think it was included in those packages. That includes a successful install on an El Capitan system (i.e., after system integrity protection was introduced).

I'm happy to solve this however I need to, but I am a little baffled as to what changed and why it's not reflected on the TeXLive pages(which I usually think of as being impressively up-to-date). What exactly is going on and how is it different than in previous years on previous versions of OSX?

**Edit**:
Per requests in the comments, I ran a find for `Tk.pm` and got nothing, and am linked to the default system perl

```
$ find ~ -name Tk.pm

$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl
```

I figured this might be helpful as well:

```
$ perl --version
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

I didn't realise it was never included in any texlive distribution.

Comment: `perl-tk` is included in *no* TeX Live distribution.

Comment: open a terminal and enter:
`find ~ -name Tk.pm` post the output.
also type and post output of: 
`which perl`

Comment: Added those per your request @naphaneal.

Comment: you need to install `perl-tk` package. run `sudo apt-get install perl-tk` (substitute `apt-get` with  `aptitude`, if you're using `aptitude`). should work then

Comment: I don't think either `apt-get` or `aptitude` exists on MacOS, and when I tried to `brew install perl-tk` it's coming back with nothing (not even a suggested package). Based on a bit more research…it doesn't seem like there's an easy solution to this on OSX/MacOS.